# JBoss | HTTP/1.1 400 No Host matches server name localhost

Tags: docker, http, jboss, hosts

I'm running an app inside a docker container and the host in *server.xml* of the JBoss-4.2 server is "localhost".
This command

```
curl -v localhost:8090/
```

establishes a connection but return "HTTP/1.1 400 No Host matches server name localhost"
and

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

gives

> 127.0.0.1       localhost 
>   ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
>   fe00::0 ip6-localnet 
>   ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix 
>   ff02::1 ip6-allnodes 
>   ff02::2 ip6-allrouters 
>   172.17.0.2      5f6b9e76d025 
>   127.0.0.1 *endpoint.used.bytheapp*

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It looks like you showed the /etc/hosts of your container.
Though, the curl command, provided you performed it from your host, will be looking from localhost within the host's /etc/hosts. Does localhost exist in it?

Comment: @Marvin the curl was launched from inside the container

Comment: Then where does the 8090 come from? 8080 is the default port of JBOSS. Can you provide your Dockerfile and/or jboss conf as well? This would be easier to understand. 
Also, does the "curl 127.0.0.1:8090" work on your host?

Answer (score 0):

The case here was about connecting to the server runnning inside a docker container whith that server being a JBoss-4.2.2.GA.
This is somehow considered a remote connection.For the case of JBoss-4.2.0.GA and later, the problem is solved by running the server with *-b 0.0.0.0*.

Reference about the option that must be added : https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss42FAQ